# Maven build failed - PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed - Mac

Tags: java, macos, maven, pkix

I am trying a build code a using maven in mac machine but it is getting failed with following error message

```
PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed: NotAfter: Thu Apr 01 00:59:59 BST 2021
```

Tried to uninstall and install JDK but this did not help. Also I tried to check cert file in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security but there is no file related cert. Any input  would be appreciated greatly

Answer (score 9):

> validity check failed: NotAfter: Thu Apr 01 00:59:59 BST 2021

It is clear : the certificate has expired because today we are after the 01 April 2021.
To fix the problem :

- either ask to the certificate publisher/owner to provide a new one with a valid date.
- or run Maven in a way where it will ignore the certificate validity date.

For the latter (with clean package goal for example) you can do :

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

If you want to ignore completely all ssl verifications, you can set all these flags :

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

To not repeat the flags at every mvn command executed, you can also set the `MAVEN_OPTS`  env variable such as :

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true"
```

**Edit**

To help diagnostic issue :

1. see the content of a certificate with openssl (Linux or Mac) such as :

   openssl x509 -in foo.crt -noout -text

To see only dates (@dave_thompson_085) :

```
openssl x509 -in foo.crt -noout -dates
```

On Windows, openssl is not required since the file association of the crt should help.

2. Make maven to run in debug verbosity (-X flag)

   mvn -X clean package
3. Make maven to run with SSL logs enabled :

mvn -Djavax.net.debug=ssl clean package

You could even use all these flags :

```
mvn -X \
    -Djavax.net.debug=ssl \
    -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true \
    -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true \
    -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true \
clean package
```

Comment: Or `openssl x509 -in x.pem -noout -dates` displays just the dates. With Java installed, `keytool -printcert -file x.pem_or_der` is another option.

Comment: Tried with above maven command but it is not skipping and ignoring the cert. giving same build failure

Comment: I see cacerts inside /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security but this not readable

Comment: @david -  Can you pls tell what certificate is this? is it java certificate or ssl certificate?

Comment: it is an ssl certificate. There is not Java certificate things. I will edit my answer to give you some hints to debug. You should have all required information to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following things :-

1. Check for communication if you are behind a firewall or port blocking
2. SSL certificate if it hasn't expired

Comment: There is no restriction in firewall. How do i check SSL certificate? I dont see cert file in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security . Should I create a one ?

Comment: @ezhil, How did you resolve this issue?